# 'stuff' and 'for xml path('')' from SQL Server in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

I'm migrating some SQL Server 2008R2 queries to Postgresql 9.0 and I have some trouble with it.
Here's the SQL Server query:

```
stuff((select ', '+p.[NAME] as 'data()' 
from BPROVIDERS_PROVIDER p, BORDER_ARTICLEORDERPROVIDER aop 
where p.OID = aop.PROVIDER for xml path('')),1,1,'')) as pNAMES
```

Reading SQL Server documentation I understand that this creates a comma separated list. I think that I can change `stuff` function to `overlay` function in Postresql'. Am I correct?

The second problem comes with SQL Server's `for xml path` with ('') as a parameter. It returns the values assigned to an attribute called `pNAMES` instead of create row elements. Is that correct?

Does Postgresql `Query_to_xml()` function  with attribute `tableforest = 'true'` do the same?

Thank you.

Answer (score 27):

You can use `string_agg` instead.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c28d1/2)

**PostgreSQL 9.1.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table T
(
  Name varchar(10)
);

insert into T values('Kalle');
insert into T values('Pelle');
insert into T values('Urban');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select string_agg(Name, ',') as Names
from T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c28d1/2/0)**:

```
|             NAMES |
---------------------
| Kalle,Pelle,Urban |
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what about 'for xml path' and 'query_to_xml'?

Comment: @user1891262 - You don't need that for the query you have. `string_agg` in PostgreSQL does what `for xml path` did for you in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,L.ROLE_SUB_CAT_ID) FROM [PHS].[dbo].PHS_ADMIN_USER_ACCESS_DTL K, [PHS].[dbo].[PHS_ADMIN_USER_ROLE_SUB_CAT_MST] L WHERE L.ROLE_SUB_CAT_ID = K.ROLE_SUB_CAT_ID AND K.UMC_ID = A.UMC_ID AND K.CCR_ID = A.CCR_ID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS ROLE_SUB_CAT_ID

Convert it to postgresql like this:

string_agg((SELECT distinct ', ' ||  cast(L.ROLE_SUB_CAT_ID as VARCHAR) FROM PHS.dbo.PHS_ADMIN_USER_ACCESS_DTL K, PHS.dbo.PHS_ADMIN_USER_ROLE_SUB_CAT_MST L WHERE L.ROLE_SUB_CAT_ID = K.ROLE_SUB_CAT_ID AND K.UMC_ID = A.UMC_ID AND K.CCR_ID=A.CCR_ID ), 1, 1, '') AS ROLE_SUB_CAT_ID

Answer (score -1):

**STUFF() with XML PATH**
**same teble to record STUFF**

```sql
SELECT distinct C.country, X.ProductList FROM     
tbl_demo as C     
CROSS APPLY    
(    
SELECT STUFF    
      (    
          (    
              SELECT 
                    distinct 
                        ',' + P.product 
                    FROM 
                        tbl_demo AS P    
                    JOIN 
                        tbl_demo AS CP 
                    ON 
                        P.country = CP.country     
                    WHERE 
                        CP.sub_id = C.sub_id    
                    FOR XML PATH('')    
          )    
              
      ,1,1,'') as ProductList    
) as X
```