# PostgreSQL 9.3: STUFF and CHARINDEX function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to retrieve some part of given string.

Here is the following example for the string:

**Example**: In SQL Server

```
Declare @Names varchar = 'H1,H2,H3,'

SELECT STUFF(@Names,1,CHARINDEX(',',@Names,0),'');
```

After referring this : ['stuff' and 'for xml path('')' from SQL Server in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119517/stuff-and-for-xml-path-from-sql-server-in-postgresql).

`String_agg` can't help me for this scenario.

Comment: So what does `stuff()` do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, It deletes a specified length of characters in the first string at the start position and then inserts the second string into the first string at the start position. Syntax : `STUFF ( character_expression , start , length , replaceWith_expression )`.

Comment: Can you show an example of output? Or describe what you want to achieve. My guess - `regexp_replace()` would do the trick but i do not understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for equivalent TSQL function of [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms188043.aspx) in PostgrSQL which i think is: [overlay](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html)

so for example:

```
SELECT STUFF('abcdef', 2, 3, 'ijklmn');
```

and

```
select overlay('abcdef' placing 'ijklmn' from 2 for 3)
```

give both the same result which is;

```
'aijklmnef'
```

in other words:

```
They inserts a string into another string. It deletes a specified length of characters in the 
first string at the start position and then inserts the second string into the first string at 
the start position.
```